# Designing user experience for an actual, real-life environment (off-screen)?

Tags: interaction-design, physical

What do you call it when you design the user experience of an actual, real-life environment, example, an office where services are offered so that the interaction between the customers and the services they want to avail is pleasant / hassle-free.

Is it also user-experience or a sub-category of user experience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the term you are looking for is [service design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_design), see the following definition from wiki :

> **Service design** is a form of conceptual design that involves the
>   activity of planning and organizing people, infrastructure,
>   communication and material components of a service in order to improve
>   its quality and the interaction between the service provider and its
>   customers. Service design may function as a way to inform changes to
>   an existing service or create a new service entirely. The purpose of
>   service design methodologies is to establish best practices for
>   designing services according to both the needs of customers and the
>   competencies and capabilities of service providers. If a successful
>   method of service design is employed, the service will be
>   user-friendly and relevant to the customers, while being sustainable
>   and competitive for the service provider. For this purpose, service
>   design uses methods and tools derived from different disciplines,
>   ranging from ethnography (Segelström et al., Ylirisku and Buur, 2007,
>   Buur, Binder et al. 2000; Buur and Soendergaard 2000) to information
>   and management science (Morelli, 2006) to interaction design (Holmlid,
>   2007, Parker and Heapy, 2006).

Comment: Service design. Agreed

Answer (score 2):

There are always roles for the parties in interaction process.
Define a process, roles and their properties first.

Then you will be able to figure out an answer to your question.

It could be [Customer Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_experience) (CX) (where parties are Customer and Organisation), or it could be Environmental Experience (where parties are Human and Environment), or it could be smth. else.

Comment: CX includes the concept that the various 'touch points' ( say web, phone, physical ) of a customers experience are all integrated together.  Its less 'top down' and recognises that customers can instigate their own interactions.